# Undefined reference to IOSurface in metal

Tags: ios, objective-c, metal

I'm trying to initialize an IOSurface and I'm getting undefined references to the all the properties.

```
 NSDictionary* dict = @{
                           IOSurfacePropertyKeyWidth: [NSNumber numberWithInt:textureWidth],
                           IOSurfacePropertyKeyHeight: [NSNumber numberWithInt:textureHeight],
                           IOSurfacePropertyKeyBytesPerElement: [NSNumber numberWithInt:4],
                           IOSurfacePropertyKeyPixelFormat: [NSNumber numberWithInt:'BGRA'],
                           (NSString*)kIOSurfaceIsGlobal: [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
                        };
IOSurfaceRef surface = IOSurfaceCreate((CFDictionaryRef)dict);
```

Comment: Show error.....

Comment: "_IOSurfacePropertyKeyWidth", referenced from:
      -[SixDegreesProvider update] in libViewARPlatformiOS.a(ViewARSixDegreesProvider.o)

Answer (score -1):

I had to include the iosframework in the xcode.